# A Star Search Algorithm Almost Working

Tags: java, algorithm, search, a-star

I'm working on an implementation of the A* Search Algorithm in Java, and it's not quite working correctly. Here is my algorithm code:

```
    public List<Tile> calculatePath(Tile start, Tile goal) {
    Node current = new Node(start, null, 0, getDistance(start, finish));
    openList.add(current);
    while (openList.size() > 0) {
        Collections.sort(openList, nodeSorter);
        current = openList.get(0);
        if (current.tile instanceof FinishTile) {
            List<Tile> path = new ArrayList<Tile>();
            while (current.parent != null) {
                path.add(current.tile);
                current = current.parent;
            }
            openList.clear();
            closedList.clear();
            return path;
        }
        openList.remove(current);
        closedList.add(current);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i == 4) continue;
            int x = current.tile.getX(Tile.TILE_PRECISION);
            int y = current.tile.getY(Tile.TILE_PRECISION);
            int xi = (i % 3) - 1;
            int yi = (i / 3) - 1;
            Tile at = getTile(x + xi, y + yi);
            if (at == null) continue;
            if (at instanceof WallTile || tileInList(closedList, at)) continue;
            if (!tileInList(openList, at)) openList.add(new Node(at, current, getDistance(start, at), getDistance(at, finish)));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Node class is as follows:

```
public class Node {

public Tile tile;
public Node parent;
public final int fCost, gCost, hCost;

public Node(Tile tile, Node parent, int gCost, int hCost) {
    this.tile = tile;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.fCost = gCost + hCost;
    this.gCost = gCost;
    this.hCost = hCost;
}
```

}

And here is the path that it produces:

[image: AStar]

As you can see, it doesn't choose the optimal path (almost does). Can anyone see any obvious errors in my code, or do you think the error lies somewhere else? Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the algorithm in the debugger to figure out why it's choosing those non-optimal nodes over the optimal one(s)?  That experience is going to be much more helpful than anything we could tell you.

Comment: BlueRaja is right. You'll want to go through your code and see why it is choosing the squares it does, as there's clearly one area where it is choosing poorly, but there are signs that it's doing so in 1 or 2 other places as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, the problem was just that diagonal movement cost the same as horizontal/vertical movement, so in reality the path it picked was indeed the shortest one (one of). :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it didn't pick the best way even though diagonal movement cost the same as horizontal/vertical movement. Just check the path. Sorry dude